# Android project with an encapsulated project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library

I don't know if is possible to realize what I'm going to write, but I will try to explain as better as I can.

1. Create an Android Project with its Activities, we can call it, for example, **ModuleProject**
2. Create a second Android Project with its Activities, we can call it, for example, **MainProject**. In one activity I have the need to show an activity of the **ModuleProject**.

I would like to do this in order to avoid the installation of two disintcts Application. The user should only install the **MainProject** which "encapsulate" the **ModuleProject**.

To do this, I tried to:

1. Create **ModuleProject** with a Sample Activity (**MainActivityModule**). The module name is **app1**;
2. Create a **MainProject** with a MainActivity and a Button in the layout. The module name is **app**;
3. From Android Studio, File, New, Import Module, I selected the source code of the **ModuleProject**;
4. From File, Project Structure, I added a depency for the module;
5. From the Activity of the **MainProject** I'm trying to create the following intent:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivityFirst.class);
   ```

   But this is not working because I obtain the following Gradle error:

> TError:Dependency MainProject:app1:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: C:\MainProkect\app1\build\outputs\apk\app1-release-unsigned.apk

I searched for solution on stackoverflow and someone suggests to open the **build.gradle** file of the module project and do the following edit:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application' --> apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

But now I obtain the following error:

> Error:Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'com.aaa.moduleproject' in default config.

Can someone please help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the applicationId variable from the library's build.gradle file.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
I tried and I have no error on compilation, but wehn I try to run the module of the **MainProject**, starts the **MainActivityModule** instead of the **MainActivityProject**. Why?

Comment: Check your Run-Edit Configurations to see what is being started when you hit Run.

Comment: Ok, now it starts the right activity but I found that both the apps are installed. Is this behaviour ok?

Comment: If you mean it is creating two shortcuts this is because your AndroidManifest.xml probably has <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> on both activities.

Comment: Oh ok, you are right, thank you!
One last thing: I tried to do the same (encapsulating and opensource plugin), but when I try to create an Intent to start an activity of the module project, Android Studio can't find it...

Comment: Refresh/sync Gradle and it should be there when you try to import the namespace and class.

Comment: I tried with the Gradle sync, but still can't find the Activity of the module project..

Comment: I can't even refer to any classes of the module project, even if they are all public. But in my sample test I can do those things..